# Converting long/lat to x/y to plot them on screen

Tags: openstreetmap, osmdroid

I want to draw a given pbf file to the screen.

I want to know how to convert long/lat to x/y coordinates to be able to draw them.

your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to process the coordinates to match your requirements. For example you want to plot a 250px wide image, then you need to start the west coordinates with 0 and outer west is 250 at X-dimension. This can be done with a cross-multiplication.
Also you might switch from WGS-84 projection to something that works better for your desired zone. The pro4j project can be used for that computation.